# Why does this user agent JavaScript not detect Opera correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, opera, h.264

I wrote some JavaScript code to detect Opera, because my site uses a lot of HTML5 video in h.264 format, which Opera does not support. Instead of painstakingly transcoding my 100+ videos, I want to redirect Opera to a Flash version of the website.

This is the code I wrote, and it does not seem to work. Why is that? Sorry, I'm new to JavaScript.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera/9.80/i))) {
    location.replace("http://mysite.com/flash");
    }
    -->
    </script>
```

P.S. PHP or other server-side language is not an option.

Comment: You should probably look in to using `Modernizr` and check for support (not validate based on user agent).

Comment: Could you instead use a Flash player fallback inside your `<video>` element to play your H.264 version in browsers that don't support it for HTML5 video? Like [the Dive into HTML5 example](http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html#example)? HTML5 is designed to be pretty backwards-compatible.

Comment: Paul- This does not work, at least not for flowplayer flash, because opera supports <video>, just not the h.264 format.

Comment: @user2170282: oh yes I see ("all elements (other than `<source>` elements) that are children of a `<video>` element must be ignored altogether"). In that case, detecting support for H.264 video (rather than a specific browser) is the way to go, as @BradChristie pointed out. [Here's that specific test in JavaScript](http://diveintohtml5.info/everything.html#video-h264), in case you don't want to include the entire Modernizr library just to test that one thing.

Answer (score 3):

Your regular expression is incorrect. In JavaScript the `/` character is used to indicate the start and end of the regular expression, so if you want to use one as part of the pattern you need to escape it:

```
if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera\/9.80/i))) {
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but still no luck.

Comment: @user2170282 Output the value of `navigator.userAgent` then. Are you sure it contains the string "Opera/9.80" in it?

Comment: Well, the dev.opera website says it does, but my version of opera returns:

Comment: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36 OPR/17.0.1241.53

Answer (score 3):

Not the answer you're looking for (in terms of how to test user agent) but a better solution (IMHO).

Have a look in to [`Modernizr`](http://modernizr.com/docs/#features-html5) and checking against `video` (with specific tests against `h264`).

Also, for what it's worth, there is a way to support video [across devices](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody).

**EDIT** As @PaulD.Waite pointed out, you can test support for this solely using the following code (from [DiveIntoHTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/everything.html#video-h264)):

```
function VideoAndH264IsSupported(){
  var v = document.createElement('video');
  return !!(v.canPlayType && v.canPlayType('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"').replace(/no/, ''));
}
```

Comment: [Here's the test for HTML5 video](http://diveintohtml5.info/everything.html#video-h264), in case you'd rather not use Modernizr just for one test.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: thanks for the link. indeed, may not be worth the entire Modernizr pack for a single test. ;-) _(I'll include the test in my answer for ref. purposes as well)_

Comment: Yeah you can customise your Modernizr download to be smaller (the whole thing is only 20 KB, and that's before gzipping), and by keeping it up-to-date you benefit from any edge-case handling they add. But for lots of things, doing your own test isn't hard.

Comment: @downvoter: Why? Just because it doesn't test for Opera doesn't make this an invalid answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `/` in the middle of the regex:

```
/Opera\/9.80/i
```

Answer (score 1):

Newer version of Opera have `OPR/` in the userAgent string instead of `Opera/`

```
var isOpera = ( !! navigator.userAgent.match(/(Opera|OPR)\//i));
```

Comment: Note that the newer versions of Opera do support h.264 videos (since version 24, see http://blogs.opera.com/desktop/changelog-24/).